# Does web crawlers follow robots.txt urls or a tags

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a website heavily javascript-based. Specifically, there's no `<a>` tags. The content is dynamically inserted in the DOM tree when some buttons are clicked, and then, the URL is changed using javascript to represent the updating.

So, my question is, if I have a list of links in my `robots.txt`, will the allowed web crawlers (Google, Bing, etc) directly access the links in `robots.txt`, or will they follow the `a` links presented in the downloaded website and allowed in `robots.txt`?

Because in the second case, the web-crawler will not find any URL appearing both in the downloaded `/` site and the `robots.txt` file.

Comment: `robots.txt` just tells crawlers what they're NOT allowed to crawl into, it doesn't contain a list of links to access.

Comment: @Barmar: "Some major crawlers support an Allow directive, which can counteract a following Disallow directive." (Quote from wikipedia). I'm only interested in these big web-crawlers (Bing/Google, both reading `Allow` directives).

Comment: Either way, it's just an allow list, not a list of places they should crawl. They get the places to go by following links.

Comment: In any case, this question is off-topic for SO. ServerFault.com is the place to ask about webserver configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Sitemaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) to give crawlers a list of URLs. As mentioned by @Barmar, the purpose of robots.txt is slightly different.